# [Logitec][Lua] I am wondering how to forcefully escape the loop

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I am curious about how to escape with a specific key in the middle of the loop
instead of escaping after the loop is over
What i want to do is that
Start Macro i = 1 i = 2 i = 3 i = 4 Aborted (when i press arg 7)
.

Full Script:

```
local isMacroRunning = false

co = coroutine.create(function()
    while true do
        if not isMacroRunning then break end
        MoveMouseRelative (5, 0)
        Sleep(150)
        MoveMouseRelative (-5, 0)
        Sleep(150)
        OutputLogMessage("Break\n")
        coroutine.yield()
    end
end)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 8) then
        isMacroRunning = true
        RunMacro()
    elseif(event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7 and isMacroRunning) then
        isMacroRunning = false
        RunMacro()
    end
end

function RunMacro()
    if isMacroRunning then
        coroutine.resume(co)
        OutputLogMessage("Start Macro\n")
        for i = 1, 10 do
            OutputLogMessage("i = %d\n",i)
            Sleep(200)
        end
    else
        OutputLogMessage("Aborted\n")
    end
end

coroutine.resume(co)
```

Comment: You can not abort the loop `for i = 1, 10 do` from outside.  This is how Lua works.  You can not execute some "parallel code" while you're running `Sleep(200)`

Comment: It is not clear from your question what is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: "abort the loop for i = 1, 10 do from outside. " When a long range loop is executed, I want to know how to escape the loop in the middle

Comment: Inside loop you can check `IsMouseButtonPressed`, `IsModifierPressed`, `IsKeyLockOn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not check if the button is pressed inside the loop?

```
if IsMouseButtonPressed(7) then break end
```

Comment: for i = 1, 10 do
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then 
    OutputLogMessage("pressed\n") break end
    OutputLogMessage("i = %d\n",i)
    Sleep(200)
end                                 -- it work!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!